# no sound launching X legacy app on libertine

Tags: firefox, libertine

I have bug here, as I trying yesterday. I installed firefox on libertine using libertine-container-manager from here ppa https://launchpad.net/~ci-train-ppa-service/+archive/ubuntu/stable-phone-overlay is working as well. But when I played video from youtube the sound is not working.

Comment: Does sound work in any Libertine applications? Can you report a bug using `ubuntu-bug libertine` please and give an answer to that question? Thanks :) Also tell them you're using the version of Libertine from that PPA.

Comment: Also note that's an overlay PPA of packages from Ubuntu Phone which may not work in Ubuntu desktop (hence they haven't been added to Ubuntu desktop yet). It might be more helpful for the developers if you tried to reproduce the bug in Ubuntu 17.04, but of course that's the development release so you might not want to install that.

Comment: Hmm works fine for me on zesty. Some details about your environment could be helpful. What release are you using? How did you create the container? Libertine is available without the stable-phone-overlay, did sound/video work with the version of libertine in main?